# Prove that $(A\oplus B)\cap B^c = A - (A\cap B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've a question:  $(A\oplus B)\cap B^c = A - (A\cap B)$

First of all, I checked with Venn's diagram, and it seems to be true.

But now I need to prove it with "if and only if" ways. I've tried something like that:
 [image]
[image]

Comment: @NormalHuman Done.

Comment: Hint: $A\oplus B = (A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B)$.

Comment: OK, whatever you say. Best of luck in coming up with a proof that satisfies your esthetic sensibilities.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I meant $(A - B) \cup (B - A)$ Which is exactly what you wrote. And this is exactly what I wrote on the second picture.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS  $\begin{align}A\oplus B & = (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B) \\ & = (A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A) \\ & = (A\cap B^\complement)\cup(B\cap A^\complement)\end{align}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Exactly what I wrote on the second picture.

Comment: I fail to understand the problem: one is dealing with a partition of the universe into the four subsets $A\cap B$, $A\setminus B$, $B\setminus B$, $(A\cup B)^c$. Check that both sides are $A\setminus B$ and declare that this is solved.

Comment: I was hoping that the OP might figure out that $$(A\oplus B)\cap B^c = ((A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B))\cap B^c = A\cap B^c = A-B = A-(A\cap B)$$ but alas it was not meant to be.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Solved it! Thanks. I don't know how you solve so fast, but I need to do like 5-7 statements before every equal u put in the answer. my teacher wants all the logic solution

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS "I don't know how you solve so fast" Read my comment (I know, crazy suggestion...) and you will know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: $A\oplus B \begin{align}& = (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B) \\ & = (A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A) \\ & = (A\cap B^\complement)\cup(B\cap A^\complement)\end{align}$

Thus the set algebra is simply:

$$\begin{align}(A\oplus B)\setminus B & = ((A\cap B^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B)) \cap B^\complement
\\ & = (A\cap B^\complement \cap B^\complement)\cup(A^\complement\cap B\cap B^\complement)
\\ & = (A\cap B^\complement)\cup\varnothing
\\ & = (A\cap B^\complement)
\\ \Box
\end{align}$$

And likewise show $A\setminus (A\cap B)=A\cap B^\complement$

Build your argument, in whatever style you prefer, around this.

Comment: Solved it! Thank you.